# Add data to slice when use range with go

Tags: go

I wanna append some data when range the slice, like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    slices := []string{"item-1", "item-2", "item-3"}
    for _, item := range slices {
        if item == "item-2" {
            slices = append(slices, "item-5")
        }
        fmt.Println(item)
    }
}
```

the code output:

```
item-1
item-2
item-3
```

I expect:

```
item-1
item-2
item-3
item-5
```

Similar to this syntax in python:

```
slices = ["item-1", "item-2", "item-3"]
for item in slices[::]:
    if item == "item-2":
        slices.append("item-5")
    print(item)
```

How it should be implemented in Go？Thanks

i try to search in this website and google, use the `Add data to slice when use range with go` keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `range`, iterate explicitly with a counter

```golang
func main() {
    slices := []string{"item-1", "item-2", "item-3"}
    for i := 0; i < len(slices); i++ {
        item := slices[i]
        if item == "item-2" {
            slices = append(slices, "item-5")
        }
        fmt.Println(item)
    }
}
```

Because you re-assign `slices` in the loop, you need to re-check the `len` every iteration to see how long it is currently. The built-in `range` only iterates over the initial value of `slices`; it doesn't see any updates to the [slice definition](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#SliceHeader) that happen during iteration.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I would prefer a syntactic sugar answer like the python demo, but it seems to be unsolvable at the moment